# Installing RHEL 6 over RHEL 5

Tags: installation, rhel-5, rhel-6

My server is currently running RHEL 5. I would like to install RHEL 6 over it. Do I simply install it and will the installation erase everything I have on the server now?

Thank you.

Regards,
Rayne

Answer (score 2):

Installing a newer major version of EL over an older is not supported, even if possible. I highly recommend you backup your existing system and install fresh.